# JavaFX perspective rotation

Tags: java, javafx

I wonder if there is a possibility to perform a perspective rotation on a square in JavaFX. When I normally rotate it on the x-axis I just get a compressed square, however I wanted to simulate a real-life rotation with perspective. The result should look something like this

[What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAL1Z.png)

Of course depending on the degree. Is there any way to achieve this, best case where it is possible to specify a certain degree.

Here is what the code for the compression looks like:

```
public class HelloWorld extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
        rectangle.setWidth(500);
        rectangle.setHeight(500);
        rectangle.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
        rectangle.setRotate(50);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 1000);
        root.getChildren().addAll(rectangle);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: paste the code that you currently have used to perform the x-axis rotation that gives you a compressed square (meaning orthogonal projection)

Comment: Googling for "javafx perspective" gives me all sorts of hits that look relevant, including many here on SO.  We expect you to expend at least a modicum of effort researching the question for yourself before you turn to us.

Comment: Have you tried the `PerspectiveTransform` ?  https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/effect/PerspectiveTransform.html

Comment: Don't worry, I did my research before and found the `PerspectiveTransform`, however as far as I know it only simulates a rotation, but I can't specify the degree value. So how am I supposed to know the coordinates of the corners for a 45 degree rotation? This is not what I need.

Comment: Related: [Flip a card animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896562/flip-a-card-animation).

Answer (score 2):

By [default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#cameraProperty), a `Scene` uses a [`ParallelCamera`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/ParallelCamera.html), which does not define any perspective. Hence the coordinate mapping for x and y coordinates are effectively independent of the z coordinate.

In order to see a three-dimensional effect in the scene, specify a [`PerspectiveCamera`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/PerspectiveCamera.html):

```
public class HelloWorld extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
        rectangle.setWidth(500);
        rectangle.setHeight(500);
        rectangle.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
        rectangle.setRotate(50);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 1000);
        scene.setCamera(new PerspectiveCamera());
        root.getChildren().addAll(rectangle);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

(As you can see, your angle is computed in the opposite direction to the angle you want.)

You can further configure properties of the `PerspectiveCamera`, such as the field of view, if needed. Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/PerspectiveCamera.html).

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX supports real 3D so there is no need to mess around with this PerspectiveTransform which is just an Effect. You just have to set up a proper 3D Scene with a PerspectiveCamera and you can get exactly what you want.